# al ingresar la fecha y hora en un inputo me aparece desincronizada con la hora local(solamente la hora)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

```
<?php
session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

$fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>ENCUESLAB</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Notable Feedback Form template Responsive, Login form web template,Flat Pricing tables,Flat Drop downs Sign up Web Templates, 
 Flat Web Templates, Login sign up Responsive web template, SmartPhone Compatible web template, free web designs for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design">
    <script type="application/x-javascript">
        addEventListener("load", function () {
            setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
        }, false);

        function hideURLbar() {
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        }
    </script>
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style-form.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-form.css">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Caption" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old+Standard+TT" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amiri:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<div class="w3l-head">
<h1>Bienvenido</h1>
</div>
<div class="w3ls-form">
<form method="post" action="envia.php">

        <div class="w3l-last-grid1">
            <div class="w3l-grid1">
                <label class="text">Nombre Completo</label>
                <div class="w3l-div">
                    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Completo" required pattern="[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]{2,48}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="w3l-grid2">
            <label class="text">Fecha y Hora</label>
            <div class="w3l-div">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="text" name="fecha" placeholder="Fecha" required value="<?= $fecha; ?>" id="fecha
                " readonly=”readonly”>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="w3l-last-grid1">

            <div class="w3l-grid2">
                <label class="text">Fecha de Cumpleaños</label>
                <div class="w3l-div">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="date" id="date" name="cumple" placeholder="0000-00-00" required maxlength="30" size="10">
                </div>  
            </div>  
            <div class="w3l-grid1">
                <label class="text">Email</label>
                <div class="w3l-div">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="e-mail" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" title="Debe ingresar un correo por ejemplo yo_algo@algo.com">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="w3l-last-grid1">


            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>




        <div class="w3l-right-grid1">
        <div class="w3l-grid1">
                <label class="text">Mesa</label>
                <div class="w3l-div">
                    <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="mesa" name="mesa" placeholder="Mesa" required pattern="[1-9]"/>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <label class="text">Nos recomendaria</label>
            <div class="w3l-grid2">
                <div class="w3l-div">
                    <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <select class="form-contro2" name="respuesta" id="respuesta" required>
                        <option>Selecciona opcion</option>
                        <option>SI</option>
                        <option>NO</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="w3ls-submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="envia">
        </div>
</form>
</div>
<footer>&copy; 2018 ENCUESLAB. Todos los derechos reservados | Design by <a href="https://twitter.com/Jesus_A_Cruz21?lang=es"> Jesus Alejandro</a></footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>


<!-- Calendar -->
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: puede ser por el timezone del lado del servidor

Comment: Te sugiero que ampliés tu consulta para contarnos de qué se trata y que el cuerpo no sea solamente el código que has probado. Tomate el tiempo y ponele cariño a las preguntas, ¿si?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes revisar la configuración del timezone del servidor. Dado que PHP se carga del lado del servidor, la hora de sistema que maneja es la del servidor donde se ejecuta. Te sugiero revisar el método [`php_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) para cambiar la configuración de la instancia de PHP que se está ejecutando.